# $1 variable in a block in an aliased method

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

How can I create an aliased method that wraps a method that yields to a block that uses `$1` variables?

More specifically, I want to monkeypatch `String#sub` (yes, I know that it is not a good practice) to modify the regexps passed to it before they are used.

I tried the following code without success.

```
class String
    alias :sub_orig :sub
    def sub(*args, &block)
        # do stuff with args
        sub_orig(*args, &block)
    end
end
```

The following test shows what the problem is

```
"mark = good".sub(/(good)|(bad)/) { "very " + $1 }
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but the block passed to sub receives as parameter the matching string so:

```
"mark = good".sub(/(good)|(bad)/) { |str| "very #{ str }" }
=> "mark = very good"
```

Can you show a more complex usage of what are you trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the code that calls `String#sub`, this is why I am monkey-patching that method.

Comment: The problem here is that $1 gets bound when you define the block.
If you do the following before calling sub you will see that $1 inside the block has the value of $1 in the main scope: `"hola".gsub /(ola)/, ''` (calling sub on mark = good will give you mark = very ola)